# Android Start activity on every 1 hour to send lat and long to HTTP Post

Tags: java, php, android

I Just build an app to send lat and long data from device to server and i want to store it in database. App is working fine .. But what i need is. I want the app to send the same to the server even if the app is closed. 
How can i make the app to wake up on every 1 hour. So what changes should i made !

Comment: You can use AsyncTask to execute any network related task or you can use IntentService for the same .

Comment: Can you explain how ? I'm new to android

Comment: use this link for example 

http://www.codexpedia.com/android/asynctask-and-httpurlconnection-sample-in-android/

Comment: If you want's to know how to use AlarmManager, do follow this. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: You have to use POST method for that so follow this:


http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

Comment: Let me try :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class which extends service and create a thread inside it and start location updates inside the thread. You can use below link for reference which I had answered a year ago. In this you can use thread.

[How to get FusedLocation from IntentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917846/how-to-get-fusedlocation-from-intentservice/29919474#29919474)